# Jupyter Nbextensions work in some of my notebooks but not others

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've grown fond of Jupyter Nbextensions. They seem to work in any new notebook I create, but they never worked in some of my older notebooks. Reviewing the spew from when Jupyter starts up, I can't see anything that might give a hint as to why, but maybe someone else can help me find the source of the problem. Here's the spew when I open a notebook for which nbextensions do NOT appear:

```
G:\DATA\EDUCATION\Computer Science\Machine Learning\Projects - Machine Learning\iPython (Machine Learning Tutorial)>jupyter notebook
[I 13:39:52.478 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 6 kernels found
[I 13:39:53.312 NotebookApp] [jupyter_nbextensions_configurator] enabled 0.2.5
[I 13:39:53.486 NotebookApp] [nb_anacondacloud] enabled
[I 13:39:53.534 NotebookApp] [nb_conda] enabled
[I 13:39:54.180 NotebookApp] \u2713 nbpresent HTML export ENABLED
[W 13:39:54.180 NotebookApp] \u2717 nbpresent PDF export DISABLED: No module named 'nbbrowserpdf'
[I 13:39:54.396 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: G:\DATA\EDUCATION\Computer Science\Machine Learning\Projects - Machine Learning\iPython (Machine Learning Tutorial)
[I 13:39:54.396 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 13:39:54.396 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/?token=a32e730ddd80639a9d1ba52af82606856b2f028a0f2ea12a
[I 13:39:54.396 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 13:39:54.411 NotebookApp]

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=a32e730ddd80639a9d1ba52af82606856b2f028a0f2ea12a
[I 13:39:54.662 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
[W 13:40:06.038 NotebookApp] Notebook NumPy (ver. 2.0 2017-09-26).ipynb is not trusted
[I 13:40:47.014 NotebookApp] Kernel started: eb66a861-e1e0-426e-81ba-eaacdfd4c47e
[W 13:40:47.158 NotebookApp] 404 GET /notebooks/images/Frobenius%20Norm.png (::1): No such file or directory: images/Frobenius Norm.png
[W 13:40:47.174 NotebookApp] 404 GET /notebooks/images/Frobenius%20Norm.png (::1) 27.02ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/NumPy%20(ver.%202.0%202017-09-26).ipynb
[W 13:40:52.083 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20170926133952 (::1) 2.00ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/NumPy%20(ver.%202.0%202017-09-26).ipynb
[I 13:40:53.787 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel eb66a861-e1e0-426e-81ba-eaacdfd4c47e
[I 13:41:50.017 NotebookApp] Kernel shutdown: eb66a861-e1e0-426e-81ba-eaacdfd4c47e
[I 13:41:51.648 NotebookApp] Kernel started: f32da744-5615-4579-b636-2183b4712eb8
[I 13:42:47.175 NotebookApp] Saving file at /NumPy (ver. 2.0 2017-09-26).ipynb
[W 13:42:47.189 NotebookApp] Saving untrusted notebook NumPy (ver. 2.0 2017-09-26).ipynb
[I 13:45:04.715 NotebookApp] Saving file at /NumPy (ver. 2.0 2017-09-26).ipynb
[W 13:45:48.451 NotebookApp] 404 GET /notebooks/images/Frobenius%20Norm.png (::1): No such file or directory: images/Frobenius Norm.png
[W 13:45:48.453 NotebookApp] 404 GET /notebooks/images/Frobenius%20Norm.png (::1) 3.00ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/NumPy%20(ver.%202.0%202017-09-26).ipynb
[W 13:45:50.924 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20170926133952 (::1) 2.00ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/NumPy%20(ver.%202.0%202017-09-26).ipynb
```

Here's the extra few lines of spew I see when I then open a notebook for which nbextensions are working:

```
[W 13:57:27.521 NotebookApp] Notebook NLP/LSTM/Sentiment Analysis with LSTM/Experiments with Sentiment Analysis.ipynb is not trusted
[I 13:57:39.619 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 73225ddd-b5cd-46bb-80ec-b9841765357b
```

Comment: Just found a Github article whose content leads me to suspect that maybe the problem with my older notebooks is not their age or version but their *size*. They are large:

https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/822

Answer (score 4):

As I suspected, [the Github article](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/822) I referenced in my comment above supplied the answer. I have a lot of LaTex markdown in my older notebooks, and MathJax is warring with Nbextensions at load time. Apparently, Nbextensions were timing out due to the extended load time caused by all the Latex markdown. The only solution as this article indicates is to increase the timeout interval in `./jupyter/custom/custom.js`. In my case, I had to increase it by a factor of 4 to 120 seconds:

```
window.requirejs.config({
    waitseconds: 120,  // default is 30s
});
```

Comment: Follow up comment: The solution I lay out above helps, but doesn't not entirely fix the problem. As my notebooks grow in size, they always reach a point at which nbextensions fail to load, no matter how big I make the waitseconds constant in window.requirejs.config. [Sigh]